# Paste into blank cells in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 72k rows excel file with some blank rows.
I am trying to paste the content from other file into those blank cells.

> I used the **Edit >Go to > Special > select blanks**
>
> Copy the data in the next file and paste.

But it gives the error "as the number of selected and copied fields doesn't match". I calculated the number of blanks and copied items which are identical in number. Still getting the error. I don't use excel much and I don't know how to write macros. I tried the same in windows, Mac Excel but nothing works. I pasted some lines manually but over 1500 lines still needs to be pasted. I was trying from last three days but nothing worked so far.

Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated. Using Microsoft Office 16

Thanks

Comment: Are the fields congruent?

Comment: Sorry. I don't know that

Comment: Can you do a sort and paste the new values at the bottom of the table?

Comment: Sorry.. I can't do that as I need them in a specific order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a helper column and put the numbers in it

[image]

Sort the data:

[image]

copy and paste missing data:

[image]

[image]

Sort Helpercolumn

[image]

[image]

Remove Helpercolumn

Comment: Hi Prema.. Thanks for the idea. I didn't get this one. Really good one. I have the data in the similar format. It will work. Thanks a lot.